# What is the equivalent to yum-versionlock for ubuntu?

Tags: apt, dependencies

I need to install `r-base` 3.0.2 because a needed library isn't compatible with 3.0.3 yet (the latest).

I can install the older version of R like so:

```
sudo apt-get install r-base=3.0.2-1precise0
```

However all the dependencies of r-base try and install with 3.0.3

```
root@foo:~# apt-get install r-base=3.0.2-1precise0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base : Depends: r-recommended (= 3.0.2-1precise0) but 3.0.3-1precise0 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I guess I could install every dependency first, however there are a lot of them.

```
  r-cran-boot r-cran-class r-cran-cluster r-cran-codetools r-cran-foreign r-cran-kernsmooth r-cran-lattice
  r-cran-mass r-cran-matrix r-cran-mgcv r-cran-nlme r-cran-nnet r-cran-rpart r-cran-spatial r-cran-survival
  r-recommended
```

I'm mostly familiar with Centos and Yum.

Is there a way to 'version lock' r and all it's dependencies to 3.0.2 instead of 3.0.3 ?

```
root@foo:~# apt-cache policy r-base
r-base:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.0.3-1precise0
  Version table:
     3.0.3-1precise0 0
        500 http://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/ precise/ Packages
     3.0.2-1precise0 0
        500 http://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/ precise/ Packages
     3.0.1-6precise0 0
        500 http://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/ precise/ Packages
     3.0.1-5precise0 0
        500 http://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/ precise/ Packages
     3.0.1-3precise 0
        500 http://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/ precise/ Packages
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's more than one way to skin this cat, but I think the simplest overall is to use [apt preferences](https://wiki.debian.org/AptPreferences) to [pin](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto) the R packages.

Create a file in `/etc/apt/preferences.d` containing

```
Package: r-*
Pin: version 3.0.3-*
Pin-Priority: -1
```

Run `apt-get update` or `aptitude update` to take any changes in `/etc/apt/preferences` or `/etc/apt/preferences.d` into account.

With the version above, any version of the form `3.0.3-something` of a package whose name begins with `r-` is forced to a priority of -1, which means “do not install”.

Another method would be to give the 3.0.2 such a high priority that apt would even downgrade towards them.

```
Package: r-*
Pin: version 3.0.2-*
Pin-Priority: 1001
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it using the command:

```
sudo apt-get install r-recommended=3.0.2-1precise0  r-base=3.0.2-1precise0
```

and any additional dependency done the same way.

Another method you can try:

Disable "Universe" repository, and add the following repository(the latest version is 3.0.2) so you have no problem with.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:marutter/rdev
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install r-base
```

Comment: With the first method, you'd have to list all the dependencies. With the second method, you shouldn't disble the universe repository as this would remove a lot of packages, but give the PPA higher priority via apt preferences.

Comment: @Gilles If i disable universe this will not remove packages, you just can't install new packages from that repository anymore and can't update apps installed from. But I like your propose. And what I mean just disable then after install enable it again.