# Temporarily override system package

Tags: ubuntu, apt, package-management

I am working with a system that requires a high level of accuracy for times/timezones.

Looking at [the `tzdata` package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/tzdata) sometimes it gets updated a number of days after the [IANA](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) update their database file.

Checking out the source of `tzdata`, downloading and extracting the database from the IANA and repackaging is straight forward enough.

However I only want to override the package for as long as there has not been an official update. As soon as there is an official update to `tzdata` from the repositories I would want it to revert to that.

How best to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a version number which sorts before whatever version number the packaged release will end up using. The canonical way of doing this for a local release is to use a ~ suffix, since that sorts before anything (and is thus considered older): so for 2017a, you'd use version number 2017a~-0.1 (-0.1 because it's an unofficial package of a new release). This sorts after the current release:

```
$ dpkg --compare-versions 2016j-0ubuntu0.16.04 lt 2017a~-0.1
$ echo $?
0
```

so it will be picked as an upgrade candidate, and it sorts before the next release:

```
$ dpkg --compare-versions 2017a~-0.1 lt 2017a-0ubuntu0.16.04
$ echo $?
0
```

so the next official release will replace it.

This scheme works regardless of the source of the next `tzdata` update (Debian or Ubuntu).

The Debian Policy [section on versions](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#s-f-Version) has all the details.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to check out [Version Pinning](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto)

Here's [another question dealing with it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120021/what-is-the-equivalent-to-yum-versionlock-for-ubuntu)

It's going to be difficult to use pinning to temporarily block until a major version though.

You can use apt hold to keep a package from being updated, so you could add a hold using `sudo apt-mark hold tzdata` to hold the package at it's current version until you know there's an update you want, then unhold using `sudo apt-mark unhold tzdata` and update